# Qtranslate displays empty categories with get_categories()

Tags: plugins, categories, multi-language, plugin-qtranslate

I am using [qtranslate (Wordpress Plugin)](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/) on a website and I don't want to display categories that don't contain posts for a language.

So when I do `get_categories()` (without qtranslate) the categories that have no posts are hidden. But when they have posts in one language and not the other they are displayed in both languages.

I know this is a plugin related. Any ideas/solutions much appreciated.

Comment: Have you reported the problem back to the original author?

Comment: @marvinhagemeister please move your comment to an answer

Answer (score 1):

qTranslate has an option to hide content which is not available in the specified language. Check the plugin options for "Hide Untranslated Content."